# How to add Dropdownlist using two foreign key References

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have three tables:

1. `MoviesTable` - consists of `Movieid` [PK] and details such as year, release date etc.
2. `Genre` - contains `Genreid` [PK] and `GenreNames` [nvarchar] consist of drama, actions, comedy etc.
3. `MovieGenre` - `moviegenreid` [PK], `Genreid` [int][FK], `Movieid` [int][FK]

I want to change the form to accommodate multiple values of genre instead of accepting one.

My previous code is here, only used two tables Moviestable and Genre table for dropdown. my intent is to implement dropdownlist accept multiples values by using foreign key relationship with "Movieid" nd "Genreid"

Is that possible?, if,what modification will I d ?

**MainClass**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Moviesite.Enums;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Moviesite.Models
{
    public class NewmovieClass
    {
        [Key]

    
        public int Movieid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Movietitle { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Storyline { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }

        public DateTime Releasedate { get; set; }

        public int Runtime { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="nvarchar(50)")]
        public Mvetypenum MovieType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genre ")]
        public  int GenreId { get; set; }


        //[ForeignKey("GenreId")]
        public GenreClass GName { get; set; }

      
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moviesite.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace Moviesite.Controllers
{
    public class MveController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        
        public MveController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public async Task <IActionResult> Index()
        {

            var displaydata = _db.Moviestable.Include(g => g.GName)
                .AsNoTracking();
            return View(await displaydata.ToListAsync());
        }



        //public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String Mvesearch)

        //{
        //    ViewData["Getmoviedetails"] = Mvesearch;

        //    var mvequery = from x in _db.Moviestable select x;

        //    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mvesearch))

        //    {
        //        mvequery = mvequery.Where(x => x.Movietitle.Contains(Mvesearch) || x.Description.Contains(Mvesearch));
        //    }

        //    return View(await mvequery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());

        //}
        public IActionResult Create()

        {
            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_db.Genre, "GenreId", "GName");
           
            return View();


        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Movieid,Movietitle,Description,Storyline,Year,Releasedate,Runtime,MovieType,GenreId")] NewmovieClass nmc)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
           { 
                _db.Add(nmc);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_db.Genre, "GenreId", "GName");

            return View(nmc);
        }

        public async Task< IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if(id==null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_db.Genre, "GenreId", "GName");
            var getmvedetails = await _db.Moviestable.FindAsync(id);
            return View(getmvedetails);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(NewmovieClass mc)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Update(mc);

                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");


            }

            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_db.Genre, "GenreId", "GName");
            return View(mc);

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        { 
           



            if (id == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            var getmvedetails = await _db.Moviestable.FindAsync(id);



            _db.Moviestable.Include(g => g.GName);

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return View(getmvedetails);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            var getmvedetails = await _db.Moviestable.FindAsync(id);
            return View(getmvedetails);
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            
            var getmvedetails = await _db.Moviestable.FindAsync(id);

            _db.Moviestable.Remove(getmvedetails);

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

       
        
           

           
           
       
        

       
    }
}
```

**DBContext**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace Moviesite.Models
{
    public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<NewmovieClass> Moviestable { get; set; }

      public DbSet<GenreClass> Genre { get; set; }

        //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder Modelbuilder)
        //{
        //    Modelbuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");


        //    Modelbuilder.Entity<NewmovieClass>().HasOne(g => g.GName).WithMany(m => m.newmovieClasses).HasForeignKey(g => g.GenreId);


        //    Modelbuilder.Entity<GenreClass>().ToTable("Genre");

        //    OnModelCreatingPartial(Modelbuilder);
        //}
        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);


        public DbSet<MovieGenreClass> MovieGenre { get; set; }

    }

    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@*@ViewBag.Header*@



@model IEnumerable<Moviesite.Models.NewmovieClass>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";

  
}




<h1 style="color:brown"> Latest Movies </h1>





<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Add new Movie</a>
</p>

<form method="get" asp-action="Index">

    <p>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Enter Movie Title or Description..." value="@ViewData["Getmoviedetails"]" name="Mvesearch" style="width:500px;"/>
        <input type ="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-secondary"/>
       <a asp-action="Index">Get All Movies</a>
    </p>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movieid)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movietitle)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Storyline)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Releasedate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Runtime)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MovieType)
            </th>
           <th>
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GenreId)
           </th>
            
            <th>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Movieid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Movietitle)

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Storyline)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Releasedate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Runtime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MovieType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GName.GName)

            </td>

            
            <td>



                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Movieid }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Movieid }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Movieid }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" })

            </td>






        </tr>

        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Create.Cshtml**

```
@using  Moviesite.Enums
@model Moviesite.Models.NewmovieClass

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4 style="color:crimson">Add a movie to list</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">



            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movietitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movietitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movietitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Storyline" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Storyline" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Storyline" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Year" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Year" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Year" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Releasedate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Releasedate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Releasedate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Runtime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Runtime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Runtime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="MovieType" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Mvetypenum>()">
                    <option value="">Select movie type</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="GenreId" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.DropDownList("GenreId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                
                @*<option value="">Select movie Genre</option>*@
                <span asp-validation-for="GenreId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>





            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add refrence of [Select2 js Libraray](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes)

in Create.cshtml

```
 <select name="GenreIds" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" asp-items="@viewbag.GenreId">
</select>
```

in contoller on Post Action

```cs
           [HttpPost]
           public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Movieid,Movietitle,Description,Storyline,Year,Releasedate,Runtime,MovieType")] NewmovieClass nmc,int[] GenreIds)
           {
   
               if (ModelState.IsValid)
              { 
                   _db.Add(nmc);
                   await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                   foreach(var item in GenreIds)
                    {
                       MovieGenre movieGenre=new MovieGenre();
                       movieGenre.Genreid=item;
                       movieGenre.movieid=nmc.id;
                        _db.Add(movieGenre);
                     
                    }
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                   return RedirectToAction("Index");
   
               }
               ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_db.Genre, "GenreId", "GName");
   
               return View(nmc);
           }
```

Comment: sir, much helped, but irelatioship code in dbcontextclass as ``` Modelbuilder.Entity<MovieGenreClass>().HasKey(mg => new{ mg.MovieId, mg.GenreId });
            Modelbuilder.Entity<MovieGenreClass>()
                        .HasOne(g => g.NewmovieClasses)
                        .WithMany(m => m.MovieGenre)
                        .HasForeignKey(j => j.MovieId);
            Modelbuilder.Entity<MovieGenreClass>()
                        .HasOne(g => g.GenreClasses)
                        .WithMany(m => m.MovieGenre)
                        .HasForeignKey(j => j.GenreId);
``` is right?

Comment: but i couldn't get the code for create view actually!

Comment: what do you mean  >but i couldn't get the code for create view actually!

Comment: [Ef core handle it automatically](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships#navigation-properties)